# Flask headers not sending

Tags: flask, http-headers, request-headers

I have an application where I am trying to send a post request with an added header.

```
resp=make_response(redirect(returnFilter(request.args,forms)))
resp.headers.add('foo','foo')
return resp
```

the `returnFilter` function is a custom function to make a link for the redirect and that works fine. I added a breakpoint at `return resp` to make sure it was adding the header after I noticed the problem and it does.

[image: debug picture]

I caught the request it would send and it confirmed it did not actually add the header but I do not know why.

[image: caught picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the `foo: foo` header to the response headers, but it looks like your screenshot is from request headers, did you look at the correct headers?

Some example code i wrote to test `headers.add(...)` method:

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello'

@app.get('/header-test')
def header_test():
    response = make_response(redirect(url_for('index')))
    response.headers.add('foo', 'foo')
    return response

app.run()
```

Request headers:

```
GET /header-test HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fi-FI,fi;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Server: Werkzeug/2.1.1 Python/3.10.4
Date: Mon, 02 May 2022 00:53:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 208
Location: /
foo: foo
```

As you can see `foo: foo` is there in response headers just like it should be.

Comment: So how would I be able to access the response headers?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about your use case, are you using JavaScript or something else to do requests to your endpoints? If you're using fetch, you can access response headers from [Response.headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers), for example `response.headers.get('foo')`.